# Add Ember Data query helper method

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I'm using Ember API with a JSON API backend. The API accepts filters like this:

```
/users?filter[simple][name]=John
```

Right now, whenever I want to make a query, I'm doing this:

```
this.store.query('users', {
  filter: {
    simple: {
      name: 'John'
    }
  }
});
```

It would be nice to avoid this verbosity by adding a helper function that works like this:

```
this.store.simpleQuery('users', { name: 'John' });
```

That function would pass its arguments directly to `query()`, just wrapping the query in `{ filter: { simple: ... } }`.

Is this possible? How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what is stopping you from creating your own method in the adapter to do exactly that?

```
// ... your adapter code 

simpleQuery: function(modelName, query) {
    return this.store.query('users', {
        filter: {
            simple: {
                name: 'John'
            }
        }
    });
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the default store. Add the following to `app/services/store.js`

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Store.extend({
  simpleQuery(modelName, query) {
    return this.query(modelName, {
      filter: { simple: query }
    });
  },

  simpleQueryRecord(modelName, query) {
    return this.queryRecord(modelName, {
      filter: { simple: query }
    });
  }
});
```

And you'll be able to do this:

```
this.store.simpleQuery('users', { name: 'John' });
this.store.simpleQueryRecord('users', { email: 'john@example.com' });
```